# Boiler Vaillant ecotec 831 R1 plate heat exchanger compability

Tags: plumbing, repair, boiler

I have a Vaillant ecotec 831 R1 boiler with original plate heat exchanger(hot tap water). My heat exchanger got damaged and I would like to replace it.

On ebay I have found a there is a bigger(more plates) plate heat exchanger that is used in Vaillant ecotec 837 R1. I would like to use it.

Do you know is plate exchanger of Vaillant ecotec 837 R1 is compatible to my Vaillant ecotec 831 R1?